# Not able to post to solr server using python and requests

Tags: python-2.7, solr, python-requests, solr4

This is the code I am trying to implement:-

```
import requests
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.autoreload
import json

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            payload = [{"id" : "978-0641723445", "cat" : ["book","hardcover"], "name" : "The Lightning Thief", "author" : "Rick Riordan","series_t" : "Percy Jackson  Olympians", "sequence_i" : 1, "genre_s" : "fantasy", "inStock" : True, "price" : 12.50, "pages_i" : 384}]
            url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json'
            headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
            # files = {'file': ('books.json', open('books.json', 'rb'))}
            timeline = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)
            self.write(timeline.text)
class QueryHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            # timeline = requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=a&wt=json&indent=true')
            payload = {'q' : 'a', 'wt' : 'json', 'indent' : True}
            timeline = requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select', params = payload)
            self.write(timeline.json())
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/query", QueryHandler)
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    tornado.autoreload.start(io_loop)
    io_loop.start()
```

I am able to query the solr server on localhost:8888/query
but on localhost:8888 where I am trying to post the data, I get this response from solr:-

```
{
responseHeader: {
status: 0,
QTime: 46
}
}
```

Data is not getting posted to the solr server.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Facing similar problem.

Comment: I did manage to solve it. But I can't seem to remember and I also dont have the code to post. I'll add as an answer if I can find the code

Answer (score 4):

The code doesn't contain `commitWithin` info in the header. The parameter is in milliseconds. Its only after a commit the data is available for search from Solr. The following may serve as an example to POST data to solr. Add the JSON header along with the `commitWithin` time and the data as a JSON string to the `data` param

`requests.post("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update?wt=json", headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}, data='{"add":{ "doc":{"id" : 14, "log_type" : "debug", "log_text" : "A transaction of debug from Kimy"},"boost":1.0,"overwrite":true, "commitWithin": 1000}}')`

Response :

`{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":128}}`